# Why is the way of setting permission by os.mkdir in python different from one of mkdir in bash?

Tags: python, bash, umask

I made directories with file mode by mkdir in bash and os.mkdir in python.
They made directories with different permissions.

My test code in command line is following,

```
$ mkdir -m 0775 aaa
$ cd aaa
$ mkdir -m 0777 bbb
$ python -c 'import os; os.mkdir("ccc",0o777)'
```

The permission of directories, aaa, bbb and ccc are following

```
directory aaa: drwxrwxr-x
directory bbb: drwxrwxrwx
directory ccc: drwxrwxr-x
```

It seems that mkdir in bash does not care the permission of parent directory but os.mkdir in python does. Is it right?
 And why do they have different mechanism?

Thank you very much.

Comment: i don't know the answer off the bat but i'm guessing python uses its own umask...  something to look into and (dis)confirm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mkdir(1)` is [temporarily setting the umask](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/mkdir.c?h=v8.28#n130) to 0 if you specify a mode, as cryptically documented in the manual:

```
   -m, --mode=MODE
          set file mode (as in chmod), not a=rwx - umask
```

Python is just calling the `mkdir(2)` syscall with the mode given and the usual umask behavior.

The equivalent Python code to what `mkdir(1)` is doing:

```
m = os.umask(0)
os.mkdir("ccc")
os.umask(m)
```

Comment: thank you for answering it. I will use bash way even in python code by your solution. thank you again.